# es6-module-loader cannot locate @angular/core in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, es6-module-loader

I used this `es6-module-loader` in an `Angular 2` project and it worked great for loading `TypeScript` modules in real time in the web-browser. Now, I am upgrading this project to `Angular 6`, but here the dependencies are not met for the `imports` of the loading module. For example:

```
declare var SystemLoader:any;

export class DemoClass {
  constructor() {
    var source = "export class Foo { " +
    "constructor() { console.log('Created the ES6 class foo!'); } " +
    "execMethod() { console.log('Executed method!') }" +
    "}";

     SystemLoader.module(source, {name: _name}).then(function (module: any) {
        module.Foo.prototype.execMethod();
     }
  }
}
```

This previous code works in `Angular 6`. It will load the module `Foo` and print those lines in the `Console`. But if I get the module a little complexity and add some `import` like this:

```
declare var SystemLoader:any;

export class DemoClass {
  constructor() {
    var source = "import {Component} from \"@angular/core\"; " +
    "export class Foo { " +
    "constructor() { console.log('Created the ES6 class foo!'); } " +
    "execMethod() { console.log('Executed method!') }" +
    "}";

     SystemLoader.module(source, {name: _name}).then(function (module: any) {
        module.Foo.prototype.execMethod();
     }
  }
}
```

Then it won't work and complains with `error 404 loading @angular/core`. So, in `Angular 2` this was no problem because all the `node_modules` required for the project where loaded by `Angular` as is, but in `Angular 6` it seems like all those dependencies are all shewed by `Webpack` and spitted all in one big fat `JavaScript` file. So, how can I get around this `Webpack` simplification so that the dynamic module can load?

**Edit:**

Or at least a sample to migrate from `es6-module-loader`(deprecated) to `es-module-loader` using the same process exposed above (loading source code, compile [transpile] and render in the client's machine).

Comment: Are you using Angular CLI? Also, have you tried deleting all of your node modules, and re-installing? (just re-running npm install)

Comment: @AljoshaNovakovic It is not related to a bad installation in the development environment, the issue happens during run-time only once the files are loaded into the server. There the files are all simplified and use other names due to the action of `Webpack`.

Comment: @JoeAlmore Are you sure the problem is not due to `source` string? It should be *"import { Component } from '@angular/core'; " +*

Comment: @DipenShah Sorry the string wasn't escaped, just fixed the typo.

Comment: run npm install in your project directory

Comment: @JoeAlmore `es6-module-loader` is deprecated so there could be something amiss with the support. Try upgrading to [es-module-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es-module-loader)

Comment: @Royson, certainly the `es6-module-loader` is deprecated, but is used to work very well for `Angular 2`. The main issue I have had migrating to `es-module-loader` is the lack of samples, with `es6-module-loader` it is quite simple as the samples I show above, but `es-module-loader` has no samples likes these above, which leads me to think that this type of loading/transpile is not supported by `es-module-loader`. Can you provide any sample with `es-module-loader` like the ones I show above?

Answer (score 7):

I'm not familiar with angular 6, but the issue seem to stem from webpack's module resolution process, where the module loader does not have a chance to pick up that module dependency at compile time. there can be couple of ways to address this.

You might do away just adding `@angular/core` as an [external dependency](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/), assuming it's declared in a compatible fashion (as common-js, umd etc.). If it's not already declared that way, you can always create a wrapper around it to expose it, e.g. as a `common-js` module.

Another way is to have a [code-split](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) point at this dependency (either with dynamic imports or `require.ensure`). I'm not sure it will do, but if the relevant angular loader (the one that parses the source text into source code) has its chance to work, and its output is compiled code, it might.

Comment: Yes, but if I create a wrapper to expose the dependencies, then I would be loading the dependencies twice in the client's machine, one from webpack and one for the wrapper.

Comment: @JoeAlmore, there's no reason that should happen